# PostrgeSQL + Django on Debian 8

Tags: python, django, postgresql, debian, vps

Good day, I've got a Debian 8 server where I'm running a few of django test apps and I want to connect them to PostgreSQL instead of SQLite. Can you please help me with this problem ?

this is settings.py of my project (DATABASES block)

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'testProject',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'adminPassword',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
 }
}
```

I think I've installed it successfully by

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib`

and

```
CREATE DATABASE testProject;
CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'adminPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testProject TO admin;
```

And when I try to access page, It shows "server refused connection" or something like that.

Thank you guys and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you migrated your database?

`python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate`

Comment: No problem! Enjoy!!